# Visual Studio 2015 can't run unit test

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

Since I installed VS2015, I can't run unit tests on neither VS2013 nor VS2015

Below is the error:

Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.

Anybody experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Update: I used Reshaper and unit tests are executed just fine, same thing if I try to run unit tests using the old VS2010. Apparently installing VS2015 screw up unit tests in both VS2015 and VS2013 some how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem (also after installing VS2015). What solved it for me was to move the solution. Others reported that "creating a new solution and adding all the projects again solved it". I think the test runner somehow marked the solution (via the path). So just changing the path works.

I think (but I did not try) that after a single successful run (move solution, open solution from new directory, running tests, closing solution, move back) everything could work again as the database should be setup correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, accepted as the best solution :)